# Xamarin Forms and Azure A2BC wrong login page

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I have been trying to use Azure AD B2C with my Xamaerin.Forms iphone  application.  I've got it to sort of work following along based on this sample:  [active directory b2c xamarin native](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native)

The sample, though takes me to a login page that seems to only accept Microsoft Logins like this one:

[image]

This page seems to only let people log in with existing Microsoft accounts.  I have set up my app to accept local email accounts, and I want the sign in page to look more like the link provided on the Azure AD B2C page:
[image]

This second version is the part of the login page that is displayed when using the "run now endpoint" on the AD B2C signin signup policy that looks as follows:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/crowdwisdom.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_susi&client_id=0729f822-6c97-4b94-b75c-df4259b0f3c5&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.crowdwisdom.co&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

I don't understand which parameter of the AcquireTokenAsync method determines which page is delivered to the app

Here is the code I run that results in the top example:

```
public async void HandleSignIn()
    {
        try
        {

                AuthenticationResult ar = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(App.PCA.Users, Constants.PolicySignUpSignIn), Constants.UiParent);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Checking the exception message 
            // should ONLY be done for B2C
            // reset and not any other error.
            if (ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
                HandlePasswordReset();
            // Alert if any exception excludig user cancelling sign-in dialog
            else if (((ex as MsalException)?.ErrorCode != "authentication_canceled"))
                throw ex;
        }
    }
    private IUser GetUserByPolicy(IEnumerable<IUser> users, string policy)
        {
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                string userIdentifier = Base64UrlDecode(user.Identifier.Split('.')[0]);
                if (userIdentifier.EndsWith(policy.ToLower())) return user;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Constants definition:

```
public static class Constants
{



    public static string Tenant = "foo.onmicrosoft.com";
    public static string ClientID = "0729...-..."; //actual client id here.
    public static string PolicySignUpSignIn = "B2C_1_susi";
    public static string PolicyEditProfile = "B2C_1_edit_profile";
    public static string PolicyResetPassword = "B2C_1_reset";


    public static string[] Scopes = { "User.read" };
    public static string ApiEndpoint = "https://foo.azurewebsites.net";

    public static string AuthorityBase = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=";

    private static string suffix = $"&client_id={ClientID}&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapi&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login";

        public static string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicySignUpSignIn}{suffix}";
    public static string AuthorityEditProfile = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicyEditProfile}";
    public static string AuthorityPasswordReset = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicyResetPassword}";

    public static UIParent UiParent = null;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code that results in the first screenshot? It is hard for us to help out without seeing any code.

Comment: Code posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting the code. When you use MSAL with AAD B2C, it's important that you indicate which policy you wish to use. That's how MSAL knows to invoke B2C functionality. What's happening right now is that you're not properly indicating which policy to use, and MSAL is defaulting back to the regular Microsoft login page, which only allows Microsoft personal & work/school accounts.

When using MSAL, the proper way to indicate policy is to use `tfp` in the path of the authority, like:

```
string BaseAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/mypolicy";
```

See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient/App.cs#L25 for the most up-to-date example.

Yes, you can also use the `p` query string parameter to indicate policy, but the way you are passing it to MSAL causes MSAL to ignore it's existence and not include it in OAuth requests.

Last comment: you shouldn't have to deal with all those OAuth parameters in your `suffix` variable. MSAL will take care of that stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how an error BaseAuthority actually gets passed to to the authentication method.  From the code sample, the command to start the login process is:AuthenticationResult ar = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(App.PCA.Users, App.PolicySignUpSignIn), App.UiParent);    None of the parameters provide the Authority or AuthorityBase string to the PCA.

Comment: It should be in the constructor of the PCA, no?

Comment: Yes, that was it.  didn't notice that change from the previous sample.  My problem now is that after authentication, the browser on the phone gives the message "Safari can't open the page because the address is invalid.  Any idea what address its talking about?  When I run the demo, somehow after I validate, the webview closes and I'm back to the app which is what I want to do in mine.  I tried putting my credentials in the demo, I get the same result.